# execute advance sql query with group by , count , group by , alias

Tags: php, mysql

I need to execute this query it's like ( main cats and sub cats )

Here is my schema:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  id | Country     |  Parent  |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1  |  India      |          |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  2  |  Usa        |          |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  3  | California  |   Usa    |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  4  | New York    |   Usa    |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  5  | New Delhi   |  India   |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  6  | France      |          |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

And I want to get the result like this:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  id | Country     | Num |  Childs             |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1  |  India      |  1  |  New Delhi          |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  2  | Usa         |  2  | California,New York |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  3  | France      |  0  |                     |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: I think that isn't possible with one SQL statement. You'd better execute some seperated queries.

Comment: You should instead use two seperated tables for this. I think it would be a bit more clear if you do it like this.

Comment: ok guys , i will try 2 tables now , but i was think get it as one table be good ( and i still see its possible  ^-^ ) , @xdazz , what do you mean , its only example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.Country, 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM world t2
     WHERE t2.Parent = t1.Country) as Num,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Country) FROM world t3
     WHERE t3.Parent = t1.Country) as Childs
FROM world t1
WHERE t1.Parent IS NULL
```

### HOW IT WORKS

My query is made of a main part and two subqueries (the ones between parenthesis); you can think of a subquery as a normal query executed in a main query returing to this some field (column). Subqueries can *interact* with main query because they can use main fields in SELECT or WHERE.

Main part gets all base countries (the ones without parent)

```
   SELECT t1.id, t1.Country
   FROM world t1
   WHERE t1.Parent IS NULL
```

First subquery gets (for every item in main part) the count of countries whose parent is main item

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM world t2
WHERE t2.Parent = t1.Country
```

Note that in `WHERE` clause I ask to match subquery id with parent id, so I get only the count of countries related to main item.
Second subquery is similar to first one, but a different field is returned using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to get all subcountries separated with commas.

Comment: you mean 2 tables  @marco :( its only one table called world

Comment: @MonaAbdelmajeed: no, I mean just one table (I called it your_table and now I edited the name) checked more than once to get every piece you need...

Comment: Great @Marco it work fine :) thank you , but i edit this code `WHERE t1.Parent IS NULL` to `WHERE t1.Parent = ''`

Comment: Can you explain your query Marco Please , i can't understand it ^-^

Comment: Thank you very much for explain the query , its new information to me :)

Comment: @MonaAbdelmajeed: glad to help you and teach you something new :)

Answer (score -1):

Check out [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: This is a lot more complicated than just using GROUP_CONCAT() to list the children